# Python Multithreading not working on Blocking I/O operations

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I've created a Python script by following an example from the book "Essential Python Second Edition", on using threads to optimize blocking i/o operations. The code is as follows:

```
import select
import socket
import time
from threading import Thread


def slow_systemcall():
    # Running the linux select system call, with 0.1 second timeout
    select.select([socket.socket()], [], [], 0.1)

# First, run it linearly
start = time.time()

for _ in range(5):
    slow_systemcall()

end = time.time()
delta = end - start
print(f"Took {delta:.3f} seconds")

# Now, run it using threads
start = time.time()
threads = []
for _ in range(5):
    thread = Thread(target=slow_systemcall())
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

end = time.time()
delta = end - start
print(f"Took {delta:.3f} seconds")
```

I was expecting the first print to be about "Took 0.510 seconds" and the second to be about "Took 0.108 seconds", with a drastic difference between the two.

However, what I'm getting is
"Took 0.520 secones"
and
"Took 0.519 secones"

I tested this in Python 3.8 on Mac and in Python 3.6.9 on Linux. Both yielding similar results, where the multithreaded usage does not seem to speed up the blocking i/o operations at all.

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I noticed something odd and replaced this line

```
thread = Thread(target=slow_systemcall())
```

with this line

```
thread = Thread(target=slow_systemcall)
```

And it immediately works as intended. Why is this though?

Comment: `thread = Thread(target=slow_systemcall())` I'm pretty sure you invoked `slow_systemcall` on the main thread.

Comment: If I included the parentheses, does it mean Python has evaluated the function before it even becomes a thread?

Comment: `<name>()` means "execute <name>", so you are giving the return value of that function as the thread start function.

Comment: @Flutterish that must be it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your edit, you must know that the parentheses are not part of the method name but are used to invoke it. As such, adding them resulted in calling the `slow_systemcall` method itself and passing its result to the target argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the new `Thread()` the function object.

By adding calling `Thread(target=slow_systemcall())` you invoke the function then pass the result instead of passing the function itself.

`Thread(target=slow_systemcall)` however passes the function, and the new thread calls it.

Comment: spent hours scratching my head because of these parentheses :(
(( thanks